# React onClick Events in loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, onclick

Im trying to bind some variables to a `onClick` event inside a React Component. Im doing this from within a `for` loop because I need many of them.

My code looks like this:

```
generateCells(pieData){
        var cells = []

        for(var j = 0; j < pieData.length; j++){
            var imageIndex = pieData[j].image;
            var image = [pieData[j].innerIndex, pieData[j].angle];
            console.log(image);
            var rowLength = pieData.length;
            cells.push(<Cell key={imageIndex} onClick={() => this.retake(image, rowLength)} fill={this.state.progressState[imageIndex] ? '#00C49F' : '#FF8042'}/>)
        }

        return cells;
    }
```

But my `image` variable in the `onClick` event is always from the last iteration of the loop. How is this possible?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're using `var` and it's creating a variable scoped into you're `generateCells()` function. Try with `let` to see the difference (the variable scope will be the `for` loop)

I did a Codepen some time ago to view the difference between them, this may help you: https://codepen.io/ArthyFiciel/pen/rxKeQR

Comment: `for(let j = 0; j < pieData.length; j++){` did not help but changing the inside variables from `var` to `let` solved my problem. I left `j` at `var` tho. How so?

Comment: This is because in my example I ref `i` (the var inside `for`) into my callback, so this is the variable who need to be scoped into the `for` (and not "global" into the function). In your case your callback ref to `image` and `rowLength` so both of them have to be scoped into the `for` and not into `generateCells`

Answer (score 1):

Change var to let in for loop. let create new binding and let creates a variable declaration for each loop which is a block-level declaration. while var scoped to the global scope so by the time you click var value is attached to the global scope and displaying last value:

```
for(let j = 0; j < pieData.length; j++){
            var imageIndex = pieData[j].image;
            var image = [pieData[j].innerIndex, pieData[j].angle];
            console.log(image);
            var rowLength = pieData.length;
            cells.push(<Cell key={imageIndex} onClick={() => this.retake(image, rowLength)} fill={this.state.progressState[imageIndex] ? '#00C49F' : '#FF8042'}/>)
        }

        return cells;
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geu71r

Answer (score 0):

Change `var` to `let` in`for` loop, this should help